# Fill algorithm it works incorrectly

Tags: java

In general, there is a code-recursion to fill:

```
public void flood(int x, int y) {

    Color originalColor = new Color(imag.getRGB(x, y), true);

    if (x > 0 && y > 0 && x <= imag.getWidth() && y <= imag.getHeight()
            && imag.getRGB(x, y) != newColor && imag.getRGB(x, y) == oldColor && originalColor.equals(c)
            && originalColor.getAlpha() == 255) imag.setRGB(x, y, newColor);
    else return;


    flood(x + 1, y);
    flood(x - 1, y);
    flood(x, y + 1);
    flood(x, y - 1);

}
```

Like floods, but the piece:

[image]

Error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
>       at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRGB(BufferedImage.java:917)

Comment: Additional Tip: `x < imag.getWidth()-1 && y < imag.getHeight()-1`

Comment: Either increase the stack size of the vm (e.g. `java -Xss4m`), implement your own stack on the heap, or don't use recursion.

Comment: Yes, an algorithm like this is pretty much guaranteed to overflow the stack.  You'll probably have to change it to make it partly iterative.  Before you do that though, another thing you could try is swapping the second and third recursive calls, (ie, do `flood(x, y + 1)` before you do `flood(x - 1, y)`) which will reduce the stack requirement.  You might still get an overflow though, but it's a whole lot less likely.

Comment: You need to return from the flood method under more conditions.  I'm not sure what newColor, oldColor, and c are, but you should return if the original color is black, if the original color is the new color, and if either x or y is out of bounds.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc That's not going to help.  He's already checking enough conditions - that the point is not out of bounds, and that the point's colour is the original colour.  The extra conditions that he's got will slow things down a little but they won't cause the stack to overflow.  What he needs to try first is to reorder the recursive calls as specified in my previous comment.  If that doesn't work, it's time for a rewrite to use iteration.

Comment: @DavidWallace, thank you for your response! 
I have changed this place and it really helped a little: https://vk.cc/5RZjr8

Comment: But this does not solve the problem completely, unfortunately.